# Internet explorer, unsigned Active-X and external DLL issue?

Tags: c++, asp.net, internet-explorer, dll, activex

We have Web application which uses Active-X to read data from chip card. With specific configuration changes inside Internet Explorer our Active-X is working fine. Now we need to implement changes and use 2 additional DLLs (to read information from other type of cards). On developer machine it works.

Our problem is how to install those DLLs to be visible from Active-X control?

We have registered Active-X using `regsvr32`. We make installation which creates dir inside `Program Files (x86)` and puts all additional DLLs inside that dir. The installer also contains C++ redistributable.

When we start Web application we receive error that file can not be found.

We suppose the problem is with the permissions but we can not figure out is is so and how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solve this by putting DLLs inside Internet Explorer directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute path in `LoadLibrary()` call, maybe it is not able to locate your libs.